# Efficient way to store data

Tags: text

I have a form grouped into different days, Monday through to Thursday.

Most days contain two classes, each with 2 different available times (some only contain 1)?

Comment: What are you actually asking? Get + Store? Get only? Store only? What is your current PHP code doing?

Comment: Ok, please, next time come to us if you are having issues with existing code. We are not here to write your code for you :)

Comment: I don't need anyone to write the code for me i'm asking for a helpful example to go on :)), Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a multidimensional array:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <fieldset style="border:#00FFFF 3px solid">
        <legend>Monday</legend>

        Yoga Class: (Becc)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Yoga][monday][]" value="9am-11am">9am-11am<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Yoga][monday][]" value="12pm-3pm">12pm-3pm<br>
        <br>
        Muay Thai Fitness: (Royce)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Muay Thai][monday][]" value="8am-10am">8am-10am<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Muay Thai][monday][]" value="3pm-6pm">3pm-6pm<br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="border:#00FFFF 3px solid">
        <legend>Tuesday</legend>

        Yoga Class: (Becc)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Yoga][tuesday][]" value="9am-11am">9am-11am<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Yoga][tuesday][]" value="12pm-3pm">12pm-3pm<br>
        <br>
        Muay Thai Fitness: (Royce)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Muay Thai][tuesday][]" value="8am-10am">8am-10am<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[Muay Thai][tuesday][]" value="3pm-6pm">3pm-6pm<br>
    </fieldset>


    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [classtimes] => Array
        (
            [Yoga] => Array
                (
                    [monday] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 9am-11am
                        )

                    [tuesday] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 9am-11am
                        )

                )

            [Muay Thai] => Array
                (
                    [monday] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8am-10am
                            [1] => 3pm-6pm
                        )

                    [tuesday] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8am-10am
                            [1] => 3pm-6pm
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I never knew about multidimensional arrays. I think this would be very efficient thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset style="border:#00FFFF 3px solid">
<legend>Tuesday</legend>

Yoga Class: (Becc)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[yoga][]" value="9am-11am">9am-11am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[yoga][]" value="12pm-3pm">12pm-3pm<br>
<br>
Muay Thai Fitness: (Royce)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[muay][]" value="8am-10am">8am-10am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="classtimes[muay][]" value="3pm-6pm">3pm-6pm<br>

</fieldset>
```

Then in your PHP:

```
foreach($_POST["classtimes"]["yoga"] as $classtimes){
     echo $classtimes;
}
```

Comment: That would work, but in my PHP after checking the arrays i would need to open a text file and save the info (eg. opt1, opt4). Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that code only save the value and not the time (9am-11am)?

Comment: Yes, I was just going off of what you had posted. Editing answer now.

Comment: Thanks, that would work good. I would vote up if i could!

Answer (score 0):

when I do this kind of stuff I usually add something to the checkbox name that gives me additional info, for example:

```
Yoga Class: (Becc)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="0classtimes0" value="9am-11am">9am-11am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="0classtimes0" value="12pm-3pm">12pm-3pm<br>
<br>
Muay Thai Fitness: (Royce)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="0classtimes1" value="8am-10am">8am-10am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="0classtimes1" value="3pm-6pm">3pm-6pm<br>
```

This way you have: 1st number is the index of the day of the week, 2nd number is the index of the class of said day.

You can capture the variables in JQuery with something like this:

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("name"); //this gives you the XcasstimesY
    var value=$(this).val(); //this gives you the value(time) of the checked value
    //here you can get this info into an array, or any other variable you want to use to submit it!
});
```

When you receive this info in PHP, assuming you are using POST:

```
$x=0;
while($x<6) //6 days
    $y=0;
    while(isset($_POST[$x.'casstimes'.$y])){
        echo "On day $x class $y the selected time was".$_POST[$x.'casstimes'.$y];
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
```